# object reference not set to an instance of an object xdocument

Tags: c#, xml

Hi I get an error on the line commented in the below code `object reference not set to an instance of an object` is there a way to fix it?

```
    private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string blabla1 = string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AuthenticateUser/{0}/{1}", textBox30.Text, textBox31.Text);
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(blabla1);
        xDoc.Element("StudentID").Value.ToList(); // object reference not set to an instance of an object?


        dataGridView12.DataSource = xDoc;
    }
```

Comment: are we doing your whole project for you? ;)

Comment: show the xml if possible

Comment: Follow-up questions don't have to be a problem. There is a 6/day limit so no need to harass the OP.

Comment: `Value.ToList()` would return a `List<char>`. Is this intentional?

Comment: You're not using the result of `ToList()`. So just remove the line and the error will go away...

Comment: @dtd: On that logic, I cannot see him using the function either, perhaps that should be removed too?

Comment: @JungleBoogie: If this is all in reference to my comment, then that was just a bit of fun. There is nothing wrong with this follow up question, it is unrelated except by the fact I just helped you out minutes before (hence the flashback humour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `xDoc.Element("StudentID")`  is not found, calling `.Value` will give that exception.

You probably want

```
 //xDoc.Element("StudentID").Value.ToList();
 //List<string> ids = xDoc.Descendants("StudentID").Value.ToList();
 List<string> ids = xDoc.Descendants("StudentID").Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
```

But that assumes the XML does not use namespaces.

Edit:

> im trying to return `result.StudentID;`

```
string id = xDoc.Descendants("StudentID").Single().Value;
```

Comment: Henk it was actually an issue with StudentID for some reason when I returned result.StudentID it never had any xml brackets around it like when I return a list it would normaly have `<StudentID>string<StudentID>` but it only had string, so your first line was correct!